# A difficulty in understanding a step in the proof of Thm. 11.5.6 in Petrovic.

Tags: real-analysis, calculus, analysis, multivariable-calculus

The theorem and its proof is given below:

[image]

But I do not understand how the last equality come from the previous one, could anyone explain this for me please?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have 
$$f(x) \cdot (f(x) - f(a)) - f(a)\cdot (f(x) - f(a)) = (f(x) - f(a)) \cdot (f(x) - f(a)) = ||f(x) - f(a)||^2$$

So, the author brings the term $f(a)\cdot (f(x) - f(a))$ from the RHS to the LHS and then just writes the scalar product of $(f(x) - f(a))$ with itself as its squared Euclidian norm.

Answer (score 2):

I'll revrite @trancelocation's answer in a more pedagogical way:
\begin{align*}f(x) \cdot (f(x) - f(a)) &= \color{red}{f(a)\cdot (f(x) - f(a))} + (f(x) - f(a)) \cdot Df(b)(x-a)\\
f(x) \cdot \underline{(f(x) - f(a))}-\color{red}{f(a)\cdot \underline{(f(x) - f(a))}}&=(f(x) - f(a)) \cdot Df(b)(x-a)\\
(f(x)-f(a)) \cdot \underline{(f(x) - f(a))} & =(f(x) - f(a)) \cdot Df(b)(x-a)\\
\|f(x)-f(a)\|^2&=(f(x) - f(a)) \cdot Df(b)(x-a)
\end{align*}
and lastly Cauchy Schwartz implies
$$\|f(x)-f(a)\|^2\leq \|(f(x) - f(a))\| \cdot \|Df(b)(x-a)\|$$

Answer (score 1):

You just have to pass one term to the LHS.

$$
f(x)\cdot (f(x)-f(a))= f(a)\cdot(f(x)-f(a))+(f(x)-f(a))Df(b)(x-a) \Leftrightarrow
$$
$$
f(x)\cdot (f(x)-f(a))-f(a)\cdot(f(x)-f(a))=(f(x)-f(a))Df(b)(x-a)\Leftrightarrow
$$
$$
(f(x)-f(a))\cdot (f(x)-f(a)) = (f(x)-f(a))Df(b)(x-a)\Leftrightarrow
$$
$$
\|f(x)-f(a)\|^2 = (f(x)-f(a))Df(b)(x-a) \Rightarrow
$$

$$
\|f(x)-f(a)\|^2 = \|(f(x)-f(a))Df(b)(x-a)\| \Rightarrow
$$

$$
\|f(x)-f(a)\|^2 \leq \|f(x)-f(a)\| \|Df(b)(x-a)\|
$$